Django Channels Config - Django / Docker / Gunicorn / Daphne / Nginx
I have deployed an app, pypilot.app using django / nginx / docker / daphne / gunicorn on a digital ocean droplet. Daphne is for Django Channels which works no problem in development to display messages in a user's console via websocket. I'm also able to connect to the websocket successfully when navigating to my droplet's IP address over http. When I try to connect to websocket via https at pypilot.app, however, I run into issues. I suspect something is wrong with my ssl setup perhaps? Please let me know if you spot any obvious issues in my setup below.
docker compose
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn unicorn_python.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  daphne:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 unicorn_python.asgi:application

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
      - ./static:/usr/src/app/static  # Host path to static files mounted inside the container
      - ./media:/usr/src/app/media  # Host path to static files mounted inside the container
    depends_on:
      - web
      - daphne  # If Nginx is set to proxy to Daphne as well

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A unicorn_python worker --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/code

  celerybeat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A unicorn_python beat --loglevel=info
    volumes:
      - .:/code

  flower:
    image: mher/flower
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - FLOWER_PORT=5555
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:latest

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local

nginx config
upstream web {
    server web:8000;
}

upstream daphne {
    server daphne:8001;
}

# HTTP Server Block
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pypilot.app www.pypilot.app;

    # Redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

# HTTPS Server Block
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name pypilot.app;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pypilot.app/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pypilot.app/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # WebSocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/media/;
    }

    location /ws/console/ {
        proxy_pass http://daphne;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}

Unsure what other information would be helpful, but I tend to believe the error is somewhere in this setup (or I've missed some other step that is required).
Tried to reconfigure both docker compose & nginx config. Tried updating my daphne command to tie it to ssl certificates but to no avail (ssl commands provided by chatgpt did not work properly). Pretty much fully stuck at this point and frustrated that everything works perfectly in development.

Hey there, no fear! Ive seen this many times before, almost every new Django Channels user runs into this problem! I have answered this question before, please check out my answer and upvote if it helps! I know that you will have to figure out exactly how to do it in nginx or switch to Apache to follow my server configuration, but read my answer and you will see what the problem is! Remember! Daphne is running local to our server! We have to redirect! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76158730/websocket-connection-failed-in-production-nginx-gunicorn-daphne-django-rea/76176916#76176916

Thank you! I'm wondering if there's something going wrong with my revised startup command for daphne.
With this command:
command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 -e ssl:443:privateKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/pypilot.app/privkey.pem:certKey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/pypilot.app/fullchain.pem unicorn_python.asgi:application
I'm getting an error that my file path to the certs does not exist (even though it absolutely does -- just double checked directly on the host)... any ideas?

Yeah thats an issue I had too, if you look at my command line in the answer I just put the certs in locally to where I was running the command so they were in the same folder. Looks like its relative pathing here so depending on where you have it saved you could maybe do something like ../../etc/letsencrypt/  but copying the file over to the folder where you run the command should work as an easy fix.

Thanks. Was able to resolve that error by moving the files to my local folder. I'm still not quite there. Should my command be binding to 0.0.0.0 on port 8001 like it is currently? Or should I just have the -e command referring to port 443?
I assume I'll need to make an update to my nginx file one way or another to match whichever configuration I go with?

Depends on what you have setup in your server configuration.You should be able to access the local server 0.0.0.0 but the application is running on the port you defined in the server configuration. As you can see in my answer,my Apache server configuration uses the local server 127.0.0.1:8001 so the local server on port 8001. You should not have to edit the server configuration to refer to port 443, we are just referring to the local application on the server. In development you have to start the application on that port when you are live on domain you have to use port 443 and ssl.

The server configuration will remain essentially the same at least for this part because the application itself will be still running locally to the server even when you move out of development
